# SSMS SQL - ORDER BY stops working when adding UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, union-all

[image]

I have 3 different queries with a UNION ALL between them. With one of the queries, I'm attemping to use an order by, which works when running that batch on its own, but as soon as I introduce the rest of it with the UNIONs, the ordering stops working, as can be seen in the picture.

The SQL is something like below:

```
SELECT CCR1.* FROM (
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
   C.URN , D.COLUMN2, D.COLUMN3
FROM TABLE1 C
   JOIN TABLE2 D ON C.1=D.2
WHERE BLAH
ORDER BY C.URN
) CCR1

UNION ALL

SELECT CCR2.* FROM (
....
```

Comment: Put ORDER BY after  all query union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL result sets represent *unordered* sets, unless you specify an `order by` for the outermost `select`.  You can do what you want with such an `order by`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM ((SELECT C.URN , D.COLUMN2, D.COLUMN3, 1 as which
       FROM TABLE1 C JOIN
            TABLE2 D
            ON C.1 = D.2
       WHERE BLAH
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT C.URN, D.COLUMN2, D.COLUMN3, 2 as which
       FROM . . .
       WHERE BLAH
      )
     ) cd
ORDER BY WHICH, URN;
```

The subqueries include an indicator specifying which subquery the rows come from.  The outer `SELECT` uses this information for the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: AFAIK you don't need the outer select.  In this sqlfiddle the ordering applies to whole unioned set, not just the final component.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca74b/1

Comment: Adding in a sort number column to each batch and ending it all with "order by sort, urn" was an embarrassingly simple solution to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should add another "order by" at the end of your query:

```
Select * fom ( your queries ) order by...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply Order by on result of UNION ALL statements

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM T1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM T2
) Res
ORDER BY col
```

Answer (score 1):

Only an final `ORDER BY` is honored for result set ordering. Although one can specify `ORDER BY` with a `TOP` clause in CTEs, subqueries, views, etc., those may not necessarily be used for result ordering so you need to add `ORDER BY` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, SQL is "set based" and a "set" has no explicit or implicit ordering.  The data only becomes ordered at the point in time that it returned from the database to the client, and only if you provide a specific `ORDER BY` clause.

In this example SQL makes ***no*** guarantees about the order of the data returned to the client...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT x, y FROM z ORDER BY x, y) sub
```

Even though there is an `ORDER BY` clause.  The existence of the outer query means that the ordering in the inner query is "out-of-scope".  It ***may*** come in the order you hope, it's just not guaranteed *(and in some dialects would give an error for that reason)*.

Similarly, the ordering of your two queries is obfuscated by their outer queries and the intervening `UNION ALL`.

It's also worth noting that when `UNION`ing multiple sets, you can then `ORDER` the results without needing an outer query...

```
SELECT x, y FROM z UNION ALL SELECT a, b FROM c ORDER BY x, y
```

*(The ordering applies to the results of the `UNION`, which is why it refers to  field names that don't even exist in the final `SELECT`.*

For readability I prefer this type of layout...

```
    SELECT x, y FROM z
UNION ALL
    SELECT a, b FROM c
ORDER BY x, y
```

To get the results you want, you ***must*** specify the `ORDER BY` in the outermost query.  That may mean adding an extra field to the sets which you are `UNION`ing...

```
    SELECT 1 AS source, x, y FROM z
UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS source, a, b FROM c
ORDER BY source, x, y
```